# .NET: How to have Escape close a MessageBox.Show()?

Tags: .net, winforms, dialog, modal-dialog

Assuming the code:

```
MessageBox.Show(this, 
       "Would you like the differential girdle spring on the up-end of the grammeters?", 
       "Smi-Boloid Stater Slots", 
       MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
       MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
```

[image]

If the user presses **Escape**, i want it to close the message box, and the `Show()` method can return `DialogResult.None`.

Related question: How can i enable the "X" in the upper-right of a MessageBox.Show to let the user abort?

---

Kind of like how a Windows Explorer confirmation dialog lets you press escape to abort.

Kind of like how an Internet Explorer confirmation dialog lets you press escape to abort.

Kind of like how an Outlook confirmation dialog lets you press escape to abort.

Kind of like how every dialog in the history of the universe lets the user press escape ,or click X, in order to say:

> "I have no earthly idea what you're
>   asking me, please just don't break my
>   computer."

---

[From the Vista UX Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511268.aspx)

> **Use Yes and No buttons only to respond to yes or no questions.** The
>   main instruction should be naturally
>   expressed as a yes or no question.
>   Never use OK and Cancel for yes or no
>   questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible, although the typical equivalent is specifying one of the *[MessageBoxButtons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons(v=vs.110).aspx)* flags with *Cancel* (specifically YesNoCancel in your case).

It should be fairly straightforward to recreate your own MessageBox function with this feature, if you really want it, though really *Cancel* does the job.

Answer (score 12):

You have to enable the "Cancel" option with the enum value "MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel"

This will return DialogResult.Cancel

[image]

Comment: or MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel

Comment: Except cancel is not a valid answer to the question "Are you sure you want to..."

Comment: ... and escape is not a valid answer to "Yes or No?"

Comment: Escape is not an answer at all, it's a "Oh god, what did i do, i don't know!"

Comment: @IanBoyd Something like "Are you sure you want to delete this?" certainly qualifies for an "oh shit no" escape button press... but Yes/No/Cancel seems dumb in that context.

Answer (score 2):

Further to the other answers it is probably bad practice to allow a user to close a dialog with escape unless it shows a "Cancel" button as this differs from the default behaviour that users expect from Windows applications and they may become uncertain as to which action they just took by pressing the escape key.

As already mentioned adding a "Cancel" button will automatically create the desired effect.

Comment: Escape means, "Oh shit, I didn't mean to do that, pretend I didn't do whatever I did that made this thing appear."

Comment: After having about the same question yesterday I think your answer is the best.
OkCancel means, you accept the consequences of what you are doing or cancel completely and nothing happens. Pressing Escape I would also usually expect this behavior. YesNo on the other side will process further and is just a switch for different consequences. That's why Cancel is a third option, without consequences.

"Deleting this object. Do you want to keep it in recycle bin?" No means delete it completely and yes means just keep it in recycle bin. It's deleted anyway. If you add cancel, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that if you include MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, by default Escape is wired to cancel which will return a MessageBoxResult of Cancel.

Comment: What does it mean if the user hits "No" verses "Cancel"?

Comment: No and Cancel mean essentially the same thing in this case.  YesNoCancel is appropriate for things like "Would you like to save changes to your document before closing HelloWorld?"  Yes: Save please.  No: Close without saving.  Cancel: Don't close or save, just go back.

Comment: But both essentially does the same thing, thats why we want an escape option!! I dunno why microsoft misses it! And now even if No and cancel mean different things, why cant I just escape a YesNo dialog! I rolled one of my own to tackle this problem..

Answer (score 1):

I think `MessageBox` (both the one in WinForms and WPF) is one of those components that are best redefined. Its behavior is so rigid that any sort of refactoring is next to impossible. In short, roll your own - that way you can have Escape close it, and anything else you may require.

There's a project on CodePlex called [InfoBox](http://www.codeplex.com/InfoBox) that could be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like MessageBoxButtons.OkCancel is what you are looking for, you are just hung up on the fact that the question does not match Ok/Cancel.

You could in theory write your own MessageBox form that does the same thing and associates No with the Escape key, that would accomplish exactly what you want, with a bit of extra work.

Another option is to rephrase your question, for example:

```
MessageBox.Show(this, "The following operation will format your computer.\r\nPress Ok to continue, Cancel to abort", "Confirm Format", MessageBoxButtons.OkCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
```

Just an example, but it is likely the simplest solution to your dilemma.

Comment: Usability vs ease of use. Hmmm